# Pre-populate the github new issue form using the querystring

Tags: github

Is there a way to have a link for a new git issue that pre-populates labels and the assignment field to labels and a user that is specified in the query string?

My use case is that I'd like to have a link that I can give to testers that will ensure they select the correct labels for my feature and also have the git issue assigned to me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found out that the format is https://github.com/[user]/[repo]/issues/new?title=[title]&assignee=[user]&body=[body]&labels[]=label1&labels[]=label2

Comment: Looking for official github documentation on this, and not finding anything. Does it exist?

Comment: I couldn't find any documentation either

Comment: Did you happen to see how to set the Project as well? I tried project / projects[] etc with no luck.

Comment: The official doc is https://docs.github.com/en/github/managing-your-work-on-github/about-automation-for-issues-and-pull-requests-with-query-parameters

Answer (score 2):

This is now:

```
https://github.com/[user]/[repo]/issues/new?title=[title]&assignee=[user]&body=[body]&labels=label1,label2
```

since Nov 2017. See: https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/99#issuecomment-343061332