# Pre-populate the github comment form using the querystring

Tags: github

I know you can [Pre-populate the github new issue form using the querystring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34146618/pre-populate-the-github-new-issue-form-using-the-querystring), but I want to use the query string on an existing issue to pre-fill the comment form on an issue. Ist that possible too?

Like

```
https://github.com/[user]/[repo]/issues/[issueid]?comment=[comment]
```

I could not find any documentation on GitHub's query string capabilities whatsoever.